# Не могу установить gem json 1.7.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

Устанавливаю плагин в Redmine

OS: Debian 10

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                3.4.11.stable
  Ruby version                   2.5.5-p157 (2019-03-15) [i386-linux-gnu]
  Rails version                  4.2.11.1
  Environment                    development
  Database adapter               Mysql2
SCM:
  Git                            2.20.1
  Filesystem                     
  GitRemote                      2.20.1
```

Получаю вот такой ответ при попытке установить gem json

```
gem install json -v '1.7.5' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'

                         ^~~~~~~~~~
                         mFixnum
generator.c:800:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
generator.c:800:25: error: 'rb_cBignum' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'mBignum?
     } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
                         ^~~~~~~~~~
                         mBignum
make: *** [Makefile:243: generator.o] Ошибка 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Прошу прощения, видимо я не посмотрел совместимость версий Ruby с некоторыми гемами.

Решение было довольно простое - поправил версию устанавливаемого гема на "2.3.0" и все заработало =)